# name 'read_data' is not defined - training data for NN

Tags: python, image, neural-network, mask, training-data

I'm facing this error. " name 'read_data' is not defined" . My system version is "3.8.8 (default, Apr 13 2021, 15:08:03) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] " Not able to find which module to install or what is the alternative.

```
for epoch in range(nepochs):
        shuffle(train_paths) 
        out_imgs= np.zeros((16,)+(256,256)+(1,)) 
        out_masks= np.zeros((16,)+(256,256)+(1,))


    for i, img_mask_path in enumerate(train_paths):

        img, mask= read_data(img_mask_path)
        out_imgs[i,...]= img #create single array of images
        out_masks[i,...]= mask #create single array of masks
    loss = model.train_on_batch(out_imgs, out_masks)
```

Comment: You didn't define your own function named `read_data()`, and you didn't import it, so yes, it's undefined.  Where were you expecting that function to come from?

Comment: I want to get the values of the enumerate function. Which contains 10 images. each for img and mask. i tried get_data, read_data. Is there any other function I can call?